# Discord.py Repeat message, delete command

Tags: discord.py

I've gotten it to repeat the message in total, but how do I have it remove the command prefix, and delete the message?

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
  
    if message.content.startswith('.say'):
        await message.channel.send(message.content)

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the bot sending the command prefix you can use `[4:]` when sending so the first four characters are not sent!

And to delete the message of the user you can use the command: `await message.delete()`

So the complete code would be:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
  
    if message.content.startswith('.say'):
        await message.channel.send(message.content[4:])
    await message.delete()

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

I would check out the discord.py documentation linked [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: The only problem with that is is does it for every message, I'd like it to only do it when I want it to, hence why the command.

Comment: @EvanSmith I now understand your question I have edited my answer accordingly. Is this now what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `discord.ext.commands` here is your code made into a `commands.Bot` instead of `discord.client`

use `.say LONGMESSAGE HERE` to  invoke the command

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@bot.command()
async def say(ctx,* , data:str = None):
    if not data:
        return await ctx.send('please enter some data')

    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(data)

bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

[Read more](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html)